# Dynamically creating a list of F combined expressions Django

Tags: python, django, expression

I am trying to create a formula field in the database for a project I am working on, at the moment I am having trouble with the numerical side of the operators, I am trying to create a list of Combined Expressions so that I can add use it in an annotation.

Example of working:

```
return F('field1') + F('field2')
```

I am trying to dynamically create the fields it should return and the operator. I have a list of the arguements coming into the function and also the operator already.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which will generate the `F()`:

```
reporter = Reporters.objects.get(name='Tintin')
reporter.stories_filed = get_your_f_function(field_list, operator_list)
reporter.save()

...

def get_your_f_function(field_list, operator_list):
   # assert operator_list size is field_list size - 1, they are not empty...
   main_f = F(field_list.pop(0))
   for i, field in enumerate(field_list):
       if operator_list[i] == '+':
           main_f = main_f + F(field)
       if operator_list[i] == '-':
           main_f = main_f - F(field)
       ...
   return main_f
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, appreciate the help, really overcomplicated this one in my head. Working perfectly

Comment: I'd have found it quite irresistible to make the function accept `*args` and be called as `make_eff_of( 'field', '+', 'field2', '-', 'field3', ... )`

Comment: sure, you can adapt in any, I just put you in the right direction